# PDF headers and footers not rendering with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I am using [`laravel-snappy`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy) in my Laravel project to generate PDF files from View templates. This package uses wkhtmltopdf.

I am trying to set some headers and footers when I generate the PDF in my routes file like this:

```
Route::get('/statement-of-fact', function () {
       $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.statement-of-fact');
       $footer = resource_path('views/pdf/statement-of-fact-footer.html');
       $pdf->setOption('footer-html', $footer);
       return $pdf->stream();
    })->name('statement-of-fact');
```

The PDF generates fine but the footer is never rendered.

What am I doing wrong here?

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      Hello 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to load the footer this way:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('path.to.your.pdf.view');

$pdf->setOption('footer-html', view('path.to.your.footer'));

return $pdf->inline();
```

And in your `config/snappy.php` set some margins:

```
'pdf' => array(
    // ...
    'options' => array(
        'margin-top'    => 15,
        'margin-right'  => 10,
        'margin-bottom' => 15,
        'margin-left'   => 10,
    ),
),
```

Comment: Tried this, still doesn't render the footer.

Comment: Make sure that your header/footer html files contains `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Run `$pdf->setPaper('a4')`, and make sure that you have enough margin left in the bottom and the top to fit your headers/footers.

Comment: Just tried that too, same issue. I took out most of my content to see if it had to do with space but the footer just never renders.

Comment: Make sure that you have enough margins in your snappy.php cionfig file: 
            'margin-top'    => 15,
            'margin-right'  => 10,
            'margin-bottom' => 15,
            'margin-left'   => 10,

Comment: Well, even if PDF is empty, you need to add margins in your config to place your header/footer.

Comment: I've added that to my spanny config file but still no footer is rendering

Comment: No more, acutally. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

On

```
$pdf->setOption('footer-html', $footer);
```

$footer should be route to footer and not to path of footer, so it should be something like

```
Route::get('pdf-footer', function(){
    return view('nova::pdf-partials.footer');
})->name('pdf.footer');
```

and

```
$pdf->setOption('footer-html', route('pdf.footer'));
```

[ref](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/174)